# Unexpected spacing on new line in outlined text field compose

Tags: kotlin, responsive-design, android-jetpack-compose, outlined-text-fields

Following is Screen shot of problem

[image: Screen shot]

Given is the code that is causing the issue

```
     OutlinedTextField(
        value = viewModel.notes.value,
        onValueChange = { viewModel.notes.value = it },
        maxLines = 2,
        minLines = 2,
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium.copy(
            lineHeight = TextUnit(1.0F, type = TextUnitType.Sp)
        ),
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = "Notes (Optional)",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium.copy(
                    lineHeight = TextUnit(1.0F, type = TextUnitType.Sp)
                )
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
            unfocusedContainerColor = Color.White,
            focusedContainerColor = Color.White,
            focusedIndicatorColor = borderColor,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = borderColor,
        )
    )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of `lineHeight = TextUnit(1.0F, type = TextUnitType.Sp)`?

Comment: I was testing with line height and it might be the solution let me check.

Comment: Why are you using a headline theme for normal text?

Comment: this is a custom theme not the default theme. I was testing with the themes and custom designing BTW line height was the issue TextUnit(1.0F, type = TextUnitType.Em) "em" did the trick

Comment: I would appreciate very if you guys could help me out in this problem coming from hybrid development it is quite a journey with Native https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77899680/mutablestatelistof-is-not-updating-it-value-on-changing-it

Comment: The code you provided works correctly. There isn't any additional space created. The issue must be something else.

Comment: Yes Indeed. As I have mentioned above the problem is in the line height defined in my custom fonts.